# How to replace text with another dynamic text in pdf in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, rubygems

I have some predefined Pdf templates which include some dynamic variable like *{{firstname}}, {{lastname}}, {{email}}* etc. I want to replace these text with dynamic data in pdf without affecting the pdf formatting like font size and color.
I did not find any *Ruby Gem* to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Habe you made sure that your templates do not have subset embedded fonts missing characters you need for your replacements?